# Tripping a COBOL flag from within an embedded SQL query

Tags: sql, cobol

So I've just recently started coding in a mainframe and I've had very little prior contact with cobol. I'm trying to check the history of an item to see if it's been manipulated, and if it has been manipulated then I want to set a COBOL flag to TRUE to prevent the program I'm working in from running.

What I'm working with right now is:

```
05  HV-ACTION-SW                PIC X(01)
    88 DO-ACTION                VALUE 'Y'
05  HV-HIST-EMPTY               PIC X(01)
    88 IS-EMPTY                 VALUE 'Y'
05  HV-MANUAL-OVRRD-SW          PIC X(01).   
    88 MANUAL-ACTION            VALUE 'Y'.

EXEC SQL
    DECLARE HIST_CHECK CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT
        LOG.ORD_I AS Order_Number
        ,LOG.CLL_TYP AS Order_Status
    FROM
        ALI.CMN_LOG         LOG
    WHERE 1=1
        AND LOG.ORD_I                   = :HV-ORD-I
        AND LOG.CLL_TYP                 = 'EMPTY'
    WITH UR
END-EXEC

IF HV-MANUAL-OVRRD-SW = 'Y' THEN
    SET DO-ACTION TO TRUE
ELSE
    IF CODE THEN
        **This is where I'd like to insert a check on the cursor to see if it's null, and
        if it's NOT null then I'd like to SET IS-EMPTY TO TRUE.**
        IF HV-HIST-EMPTY = 'Y' THEN
            CONTINUE
        ELSE
            SET DO-ACTION   TO TRUE
        END-IF
    ELSE
        SET DO-ACTION       TO TRUE
    END-IF
END-IF
```

EDIT: Could I do a fetch on the cursor and if it returns SQLCODE 100 then set is-empty to true?

Answer (score 2):

> Could I do a fetch on the cursor and if it returns SQLCODE 100 then
>   set is-empty to true?

Yes.  I've seen that done often, after opening the cursor of course.

I would suggest that, instead of coding e.g.

```
IF HV-MANUAL-OVRRD-SW = 'Y'
```

...you code...

```
IF MANUAL-ACTION
```

...as it's more COBOLish.

Comment: cschneid, wanted to ping you, would you please take a look at my Meta post "[Merge/cleanup tags \[zos\], \[mvs\], \[zseries\], and \[mainframe\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370743/merge-cleanup-tags-zos-mvs-zseries-and-mainframe)" and comment as someone who has much more knowledge about these tags than I do?

Answer (score 2):

You have only `DECLARED` a cursor, you have not yet `OPENED` it or attempted to `FETCH` anything from it.
You will not know if any rows match the predicate until a `FETCH` is attempted, at which time you can check
for SQLCODE +100 (Row not found). Take a couple of minutes to GOOGLE for a 
COBOL DECLARE, OPEN, FETCH example program (for example: https://www1.columbia.edu/sec/acis/db2/db2a0/db2a020.htm)

Also ask yourself if you should be using an isolation level of `UR` and maybe question why you need to
specify `WITH HOLD` on the cursor (only required when processing a cursor over multiple commit points)